# Can I host Aurelia app on GoDaddy shared hosting?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, aurelia, shared-hosting

I'm planning to pick up a cool Client Framework so I'm considering Aurelia with Typescript and Webpack for bundling. Can I host an aurelia app on GoDaddy shared hosting plan?
If yes, how can I go about it and if no, please what other hosting options do I have?

Comment: Yes because the app is compiled to static JavaScript and CSS files.

Comment: I'd like to add that you have to consider in which path your app will be server: is it a "root level directory"? If not, you'd have to tweak the "baseUrl" defined in the webpack configuration. Please see the following discussion: https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/programatically-set-baseurl-in-webpack-config-on-build/1358

Comment: Another thing is that I normally use the Azure range of services. In this case, to serve static aurelia apps, I normally create a Storage Account. There you can enable a static web site, a CDN and DNS zones all with Azure managed HTTPS certificates.

Comment: You can host it. But, personally you better think twice if you want to host your site with them. I worked with them previously, they were not too good. So, I migrated to Asphostportal, I've been with Asphostportal for years, I can't recommend them highly enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course. Aurelia is bundled into plain css/html/js using Webpack/Babel/Gulp (Depending on your CLI Options)

You will take the output of that (usually put into a dist folder once running your build) and that is what you'll use inside your /www/ (this is the most common place) folder inside your hosting solution.